# Can you return multiple arrays in a single solidity getter function?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

The reason I'm asking this is because I came across two answers, one of which saying that you can return multiple arrays in a function
and another answer saying you cannot.

The answer saying it's possible to return two arrays in a single function:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/121362

The answer saying you cannot (It also links to an expired documentation page):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer depends on the version. in old versions you could not and in new versions you can. solidity has been evolved since v4 till v9. you can test this on your own with remix ide.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 


contract Test{
    function test() public pure returns (uint8 [1] memory,uint8 [1] memory) {
        return ([2],[1]);
    }
}
```

here is the result:

[image]